# How to extract a sub-column from a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a table with three columns: **A, B** and **C**. Each column is further divided into two sub-columns: *Name* and *Rule*.

I need to plot three pie charts out the *Name* sub-columns using matplotlib, but I don't know how to extract the sub-column. This is what I tried, but it did not work:

```
chart = df['A'['Name']].value_counts().plot(kind='pie', labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to read on Multiindexing and [Slicing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arrays = [['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
          ['Name', 'Rule', 'Name', 'Rule', 'Name', 'Rule']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3, 6)*10, columns=index)

#creates this dataframe:
#first          A                   B                   C          
#second      Name      Rule      Name      Rule      Name      Rule
#0       2.075001  4.702192  3.480122  1.785579  5.078655  9.053004
#1       7.313122  3.762273  7.423559  8.713660  9.107358  5.643705
#2       8.981356  9.748874  1.131691  1.487273  0.096690  6.175825

# then index it with a none slice for the first column index and `"Name"` for the second.

df.loc[:,(slice(None), 'Name')].plot(kind='pie', subplots=True, autopct='%1.1f%%')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I've been trying to implement it, but get a mistake "'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (1)'". Do you know what this mistake can refer to? 

I have strings in this table as opposed to numbers which you've imported using np.random.

Comment: I think you will understand that it's close to impossible to know the problem you have without knowing the code.

Comment: Sorry, that's my code. There are some additional columns in the table (Name2, Rule2), but I don't need them for plotting.

`arrays = [['A', 'A','A','A',
           'B','B', 'B', 'B',
           'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
          ['Name', 'Rule', 'Name2', 'Rule2', 
           'Name', 'Rule', 'Name2', 'Rule2', 'Name', 'Rule', 'Name2', 'Rule2']]

tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
df_new = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=index)

df_new.loc[:,(slice(None), 'Name')].plot(kind='pie', subplots=True, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')`

Comment: maybe I need to explain it a little better: You have two options: (1) edit your question to include the problem you now have, (2) ask a new question about it. In any case, you need to provide a [mcve] of the issue. Here it's crucial to know what `df` is.