# Pandas Advanced MultiIndex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two data arrays `columns` and `values`.

```
columns = ['A','B', ...]
sub_columns = ['sc1', 'sc2', 'sc3'] # fixed
values = [[[1,4,10],[2,5,6]],[[1,0.2,0.3],[2,0.2,0.6]], ...]
```

I would like to obtain a MultiIndexed DataFrame that looks like this, where `sc1` is the index of the new DataFrame.
[image: Final Result]

I have tried to create first a DataFrame with columns `sc1, sc2, sc3` and then pivoting it to obtain the index, but I have no idea how to put also the outer columns in the new DataFrame.

Comment: "I have tried to create first a DataFrame with columns sc1, sc2, sc3..." Would help to see the code here. This answer may help you out https://stackoverflow.com/a/44650884/9357244

Comment: @chris, this was very useful, thank you. I have some problems setting the values of the DF as they are row-ordered and not column-ordered but I have somewhere to start now!